# How can i display the input only after pressing enter in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

After entering the location, it returns the value of temperature etc. But I want the temperature value to be hidden if the user doesn't enter the location. Currently my code is like this

```
const [temp, setTemp] = useState('');

<Text style={styles.tempText}> temp:{temp}  {`${Math.round(data?.main?.temp,)} °C`}</Text>
```

This is my code for the text input:

```
<View>
      <TextInput placeholder='Enter city name and Enter'
        onChangeText={text => setInput(text)}
        value={input}
        placeholderTextColor={'#000'}
        style={styles.textInput}
        onSubmitEditing={fetchDataHandler}
      />
    </View>
```

This is my styles for fetchdatahandler:

```
const fetchDataHandler = useCallback(() => {
setLoading(true);
setInput("");
axios({
  method:'GET',
  url: `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input}&units=metric&appid=${api.key}`,
})
.then(res =>{
  console.log(res.data);
  setData(res.data);
}).catch(e=>console.dir(e))
.finally(()=> setLoading(false));


}, [api.key,input]);
```

Constants

```
const [input, setInput] = useState("Singapore"); //input is empty string by default


const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: how can you get user locations? in Textinput?

Comment: Hi! yes! Currently its getting the desired location from text input. I can assign the input a placeholder using setInput in const. But the user will have to click enter for the data to load

Comment: I'm thinking somewhere along the constants? do i have to input the data by calling the api?

Answer (score 0):

```
temp!="" && <Text style={styles.tempText}> temp:{temp}  {`${Math.round(data?.main?.temp,)} °C`}</Text>
```

use it where you are showing temp, it will return nothing when your temp would be empty, after hitting enter, you API call will be done and temp value will set with new value, in this case it will print your temperature value

Hopefully it will help you

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much for your reply but it is showing error. I think syntax error

Comment: {temp!="" ?( <Text style={styles.tempText}> temp:{temp}  {`${Math.round(data?.main?.temp,)} °C`}</Text>):null}

use it

Comment: sorry im using this .. {temp!= "" ? (<Text placeholder="hello" style={styles.tempText}> Temp:{temp}  {`${Math.round(data?.main?.temp,)} °C`}</Text>):null}  .. and it is just returning blank